# what does "scalar mean curvature of $\partial E$ with orientation induced by the inner normal to E" mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, calculus-of-variations

I'm currently reading the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.3899.pdf and I have a question regarding the mean curverture stuff in it (unfortunately, I don't have any knowledge in differential geometry)- Lemma 3.7.

The situation is the following:

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Borel set with positive and finite Lebesgue measure. Even better we consider $\partial E$ to be of class $C^{1,\eta}(B_1(0))$ for all $\eta \in (0,1)$ and such that $\partial E$ is a nonparametric surface in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, i.e. a graph of a function $f\in C^1(B_1(0))$ (see theorem 3.2 (ii) ).

How is the scalar mean curvature of $\partial E$ with orientation induced by the inner normal to E defined? (see lemma 3.7)

I already 'found out' that the scalar mean curvature of $\partial E$, $H$,  is defined as 
$$H:=\frac{1}{n-1}\text{div}\big(\frac{\nabla f(x)}{\sqrt{1+\|\nabla f(x)\|^2 }} \big).$$

And what is the inner normal to $E$, is that $\nu =-\frac{\nabla f(x)}{\sqrt{1+\|\nabla f(x)\|^2 }}$?

I guess that the scalar mean curvature of $\partial E$ with orientation induced by the inner normal to E is $-H$?

Thank you.

Comment: So what precisely is $f$?

Comment: oops, edit done. $\partial E$ can be written is a graph of a $C^1$-function

Comment: But you need, then, to specify which direction $\nabla f$ points relative to $E$. Anyhow, if $z=f(x)$, then a unit normal vector will be $\pm (\nabla f(x),-1)/\sqrt{1+\|\nabla f(x)\|^2}$.